# upload pdf file from ionic 3 app to amazon s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, ionic3

I want to upload pdf file to amazon s3 bucket. but only the file path is getting upload not the file

```
var filepath = "";
var that = this;
this.fileChooser.open()
  .then(uri => {
    console.log(uri);
    filepath = uri;

    var fileName = 'File_' + this.global.gerUniqueString() + ".pdf";

    var AWSService = window.AWS;
    AWSService.config.accessKeyId = this.global.accessKeyId;
    AWSService.config.secretAccessKey = this.global.secretAccessKey;
    AWSService.config.region = 'ap-south-1';
    var bucket = new AWSService.S3({ params: { Bucket: this.global.bucketName } });
    var body = 'data:application/pdf', base64, filepath;
    var params = { Key: fileName, Body: body };
    bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {

      console.log(err, data);

    });

  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies with this code:

```
var body = 'data:application/pdf', base64, filepath;
var params = { Key: fileName, Body: body };
```

Change to:

```
var params = {Key: filename, ContentType: 'application/pdf', Body: filepath};
```

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `base64`.